# Prevent event from triggering together with another event

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have google.maps event handler

```
google.maps.event.addListener('place_changed', function(){
  ...
})
```

attached to input (which is also autocomplete) and another handler attached to the same input

```
input.addEventListener('change', function(){
...
})
```

How can i prevent *change* from triggering together with *place_changed*? To be accurate, if *place_changed* then dont trigger *change* and not vice versa.

I tried

```
google.maps.event.addListener('place_changed', function(){
    input.addEventListener('change', function(){
       return 0;
    })

})
```

but it didn't help

Comment: Try event.stopPropagation()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I read you want to not trigger *event a* when *event b* is being triggered?

That's pretty easy:

```
window.e_called = false;
function e1()
{
    window.e_called = true;
    // event 1 code...
}

function e2()
{
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        if(!window.e_called)
        {
             // event 2 code...
        }
        window.e_called = false;
    }, 1);
}
```

You of course have to bind `e1()` and `e2()` and all that stuff, but I hope you understand my solution.